# Pattern matching with grep

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have a full path of a file say `hai/hello/home/something/file.txt` .How can I get `file.txt` as output eliminating full path?

How to do that with grep?

Comment: Why does it have to be with grep?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Spec;
use File::Basename;
$n="hai/hello/home/something/file.txt";
my $m = basename $n;
print "$m";
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't strictly need grep for this, but if you insist, this should work:

```
grep -o -e "\w*\.\w*$"
```

Optionally, consider the command [basename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html):

```
basename hai/hello/home/something/file.txt
```

Comment: Please leave a comment if down-voting, explaining why. Otherwise it helps nobody.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [**`sed`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed):

```
$ echo hai/hello/home/something/file.txt | sed "s|.*/||g"
file.txt
```

or, easier, [**`basename`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename):

```
$ basename hai/hello/home/something/file.txt
file.txt
```